# blockchain size issue

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain, blockchain.info

I am running full bitcoin node locally. Currently, the size of the blockchain is around 70 GB.
[Blockchain size](https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size?timespan=all)

Further, I stored all the blocks in a text file in json format. It turned out that the size of this text file is around 10 GB. I am wondering what is the rest of the 60 GB used for?

Comment: Can guarantee you that the JSON files do not contain all the information. How did you create those JSON files?

Comment: please see [link]https://github.com/tariq786/datafying_bitcoin/blob/master/batch_load_blocks_rpc.py . This is how i generate blocks in json format. Essentially using JSON RPC with bitcoind

Comment: I only glanced at the code for that JSON extractor tool, but I'm going to bet that it doesn't include any signature information. Not sure what else will be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code stores only the results of the `getblock` call. This returns the block headers and the tx hashes of the block, but [NOT the actual tx's themselves](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getblock).

Each transaction hash is only 8 bytes, an actual transaction is roughly 500 bytes, so you're missing about 500 bytes per tx in each block.

There have been [about 116 million transactions](https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions-total) in the history of bitcoin, so 500 * 116 million ~ 60 billion bytes or about 60 GB that you're missing.